# Autocomplete not working while exporting environment variable in bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Suppose I wish to export an environment variable named `MYPATH` holding following 2 paths:

1. /full/path/to/fileA
2. /another/full/path/to/fileB

So, I think it should be done like this in bash:

```
$export MYPATH=/full/path/to/fileA:/another/full/path/to/fileB
```

The issue I'm facing is auto-complete (<kbd>Tab</kbd> key) works while writing path A in command, but after `:` auto-complete stops working, so it is difficult to write path B in the console in absence of auto-complete.

Surprisingly, it works if:

- I use semi-colon instead of colon, but that's not correct path
  separator anyway.
- I am root user.

**Can someone please explain the reason for this behavior?**

- Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release
  (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- Bash-completion version: all/xenial-updates 1:2.1-4.2ubuntu1.1
- OS version: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: Is bash-completion installed on your system? I'm getting some inconsistent behavior on the systems I can test with, depending on bash-completion's version. With bash-completion not sourced/not installed, completion of `export mypath=/path/1:/path/2` works (even after any `:`) on various Bash versions -- I don't have any Bash 4.3, though.

Comment: @fra-san I do have /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh in my system (Ubuntu 16.04), but I'm not sure if it is having any effect, I didn't install it manually or I didn't made changes around this area, using default OS settings. Could you reprodue the issue on any of your systems?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the behavior you described with bash-completion 2.9; with version 2.1 I get no completion at all for `export myvar=`; with version 1.3, `export mypath=/path/1:/path/2` has working auto-completion for `/path/2`, too. Please, add your bash-completion (and operating system) version to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is likely caused by [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion).

(What follows is based on the current version of the package (2.9), but it will be reasonably accurate for the 2.1 version you have too).

bash-completion provides a set of completion specifications (*[compspec](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html#Programmable-Completion)*) that the Readline library uses to complete words that are supplied as arguments to commands in Bash. They are defined using the `complete` [builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins), usually in the form:

```
complete -F function command
```

For the `export` builtin, the function `_export` is defined in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/export`.

When the word to complete includes (or ends in) a `=`, `_export` tries to complete it (the part to the right of the first `=`, actually) as a file or directory name; when the word to complete does not include a `=`, it tries to complete it as a variable name. Since the Readline library starts a new completion every time it runs across one of the characters listed in the `COMP_WORDBREAKS` variable (unless the character is escaped), which usually includes `:`, completion stops working after the first colon you append to a variable's value because, at that point, the word to complete is not including (or ending in) a `=` anymore.
(Note, incidentally, that file/directory name completion starts working again if you write `export myvar=/usr/:othervar=` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

bash-completion indeed has its own mechanism for handling special cases. For instance, `:` is correctly dealt with by the compspec for `scp`, which interprets what is on the right hand of a colon as a remote path. The same is not applied to `export`, though.

Readline's [default behavior](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html#Commands-For-Completion), which is triggered when a compspec for the current command is not found, is ultimately to attempt filename completion. That is why completion of `path2` in `export var=/path1/:/path2/` works when bash-completion is not installed or otherwise disabled (remember that every colon starts a new completion).

What can you do, then? You have some alternatives:

1. File a feature request to [bash-completion on GitHub](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/issues).
2. Define your own completion function for `export`.
   First, copy the compspec to the user completion file (which likely doesn't exist yet):

   ```bash
   $ cat /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/export >>~/.bash_completion
   ```

   Then edit `~/.bash_completion`, changing `complete -F _export export` into `complete -F _export -o default export`. This instructs Readline to attempt the default completion when `export`'s specific compspec gives no results.
3. Use the default completion, instead of the one provided by bash-completion.
   Add to your `~/.bashrc`:

   ```bash
   complete -o default -o bashdefault export
   ```

   (Suggestion from [bash-completion's FAQ](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion)). The downside is that you lose the ability to complete variable names and `export` options.
4. If you are willing to become familiar enough with bash-completion, define your own `_export` function, as in (2), by editing the provided one to let it handle `:` specially.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! That also explains why it is working for the root user because, there, default completion is in effect on my system.

Comment: @SagarGuptaFTW Yes -- I thought it could be like that, but I couldn't actually check/test that bit; so I left it out of my answer. Glad it helped.